# Javascript - String Inline styling

Tags: javascript, string, node-pdfkit

I'm using https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit in order to create PDF in node.js.

I have a string `markup` which contains my content and Here's my problem:

```
let markup = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit <strong>amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</strong>. Proin varius dictum magna sit amet dignissim. Donec vitae turpis commodo, interdum turpis vitae, tempus tellus. Nam dictum nunc erat, ac consectetur urna convallis in. Vivamus dignissim sapien nulla, ut elementum <em>massa venenatis sit amet</em>. Nunc lobortis lectus ut metus faucibus convallis. Curabitur nec ante ac magna vulputate bibendum quis a ex. Cras condimentum tempor elementum."
```

As you can see the string contains html entities such as `<strong/>` and `<em/>`, and PDFKIT uses `markup.font('bold-font').text();` (http://pdfkit.org/docs/text.html#fonts) in order to insert bold text;

How can I possibly convert all the tags to functions?

I was thinking about splitting and RegExp method but I think it'll be too heavy in case of longer strings.

Comment: The answer is perhaps not what you expected, but I would write a parser.

Comment: @DevAggarwal what about https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Last commit was on 4 Oct 2017. I don't think that lib is maintained now. Refer to github issues.

Comment: @ThomasJunk Can you please help me with writing a parser?